# Method to find a factor of a number

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, primes, factors

I am trying to write a simple program that takes a non-prime number and returns the first factor of it. I have to use a method to do this. I think that I am really close to the correct code, but I keep running into variable definition issues in my method. Here is my (currently incorrect) code:

```
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a;

        a = 42;

        System.out.println(factor(a));

    }

    //This method finds a factor of the non-prime number
    public static int factor(int m) {   
        for(int y=2 ; y <= m/2 ; y++) {
            if(m%y==0) {
                return y;
                continue;
            }
        }
    return y;
    }
}
```

Please let me know what's incorrect!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: One performance improvement is to limit the search space, done by having your for loop's terminating condition be when `y <= m*m` and not `m/2`.

Comment: @hd1, that actually makes the search space _bigger,_ I suspect you mean `y <= sqrt(m)`, or `y * y <= m`.

Comment: I did, was going for `m**.5`. Thanks @paxdiablo

Comment: you are writing **continue** after **return** that is unreachable statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your code:

```
public static int factor(int m) {   
    for(int y=2 ; y <= m/2 ; y++) {
        if(m%y==0) {
            return y;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

At the point of that final `return y`, `y` does not exist. Its scope is limited to the inside of the `for` statement since that is where you create it. That's why you're getting undefined variables.

In any case, returning `y` when you can't find a factor is exactly the *wrong* thing to do since, if you pass in (for example) `47`, it will give you back `24` (`47 / 2 + 1`) despite the fact it's not a factor.

There's also little point in attempting to continue the loop *after* you return :-) And, for efficiency, you only need to go up to the square root of `m` rather than half of it.

Hence I'd be looking at this for a starting point:

```
public static int factor (int num) {   
    for (int tst = 2 ; tst * tst <= num ; tst++)
        if (num % tst == 0)
            return tst;
    return num;
}
```

This has the advantage of working with prime numbers as well since the first factor of a prime is the prime itself. And, if you foolishly pass in a negative number (or something less than two, you'll also get back the number you passed in. You *may* want to add some extra checks to the code if you want different behaviour.

---

And you can make it even faster, with something like:

```
public static int factor (int num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) return 2;
    for (int tst = 3 ; tst * tst <= num ; tst += 2)
        if (num % tst == 0)
            return tst;
    return num;
}
```

This runs a check against `2` up front then simply uses the *odd* numbers for remainder checking. Because you've already checked `2` you know it cannot be a multiple of any even number so you can roughly double the speed by only checking odd numbers.

---

If you want to make it even faster (potentially, though you should check it and keep in mind the code may be harder to understand), you can use a clever scheme pointed out by Will in a comment.

If you think about the odd numbers used by my loop above with some annotation, you can see that you periodically get a multiple of three:

```
 5
 7
 9   = 3 x 3
11
13
15   = 3 x 5
17
19
21   = 3 x 7
23
25
27   = 3 x 9
```

That's mathematically evident when you realise that each annotated number is six (`3 x 2`) more than the previous annotated number.

Hence, if you start at five and alternately add two and four, you will skip the multiples of three as well as those of two:

```
5, +2=7, +4=11, +2=13, +4=17, +2=19, +4=23, ...
```

That can be done with the following code:

```
public static long factor (long num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) return 2;
    if (num % 3 == 0) return 3;
    for (int tst = 5, add = 2 ; tst * tst <= num ; tst += add, add = 6 - add)
        if (num % tst == 0)
            return tst;
    return num;
}
```

You have to add testing against `3` up front since it violates the `2, 4, 2` rule (the sequence `3, 5, 7` has *two* consecutive gaps of two) but that may be a small price to pay for getting roughly *another* 25% reduction from the original search space (over and above the 50% already achieved by skipping all even numbers).

Setting `add` to `2` and then updating it with `add = 6 - add` is a way to have it alternate between `2` and `4`:

```
6 - 2 -> 4
6 - 4 -> 2
```

As I said, this *may* increase the speed, especially in an environment where modulus is more expensive than simple subtraction, but you would want to actually benchmark it to be certain. I just provide it as another *possible* optimisation.

Comment: `for( y=5, k=4; ...; y += (k=6-k) ) ...`. :)

Comment: @Will, that's a rather nifty trick. I couldn't easily google it since `j k` turns up quite a few pages :-) And I couldn't add it to the answer without a mathematical basis. But I think I nutted it out enough to explain it, so I've added it in. Cheers.

Comment: that's "wheel factorization" with 2-3 wheel. -- also, [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21310956/849891) I tried to show its derivation, in a more visual way.

Comment: If `(%)` is as efficient as `(-)`, there's also the loop unrolling `for( y=5,z=7; ...; y+=6, z+=6) ...` which eliminates the two `(-)` operations at the price of one potential extra `(%)` check above the `sqrt(n)` (negligible). Indeed, maybe it should always be shown this way, not how I first mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you probably want to do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a;

    a = 42;

    System.out.println(factor(a));
}

public static int factor(int m) {

    int y = 0;
    for (y = 2; y <= m / 2; y++) {
        if (m % y == 0) {
            return y;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

And the output will be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

we need just a simple for loop like,

```
public static void finfFactor(int z) {
for(int x=1; x <= z; x++) {
    if(z % x == 0) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```